# How can i compose two columns to apply a filter?

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

I have a table with two columns: `first_name` and `last_name`. At the application the user sees the full name (eg first + last names).

Example:

```
first_name   last_name
bat          man
Barack       Obama
```

In the application if the user searches for "bat man" he got no result.
So, how can I filter using both columns?

My current sql:

```
select * 
from people 
where first_name ilike 'bat man' 
or last_name ilike 'bat man'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for the string concatenation operator, `||`:

```
SELECT *
  FROM people
 WHERE (first_name || ' ' || last_name) ILIKE 'bat man'
```

See [§9.4 "String Functions and Operators" in *PostgreSQL 9.4.4 Documentation*](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-string.html).

Comment: The trouble with this is that it makes the query unsargable so every query would have to scan the entire table. Fortunately, Postgresql has a function index that can be created: *create index people_full_name on people( first_name || ' ' || last_name );*. From then on the clause "where people_full_name ilike 'bat man'" would use the index.

Comment: @TommCatt: Sorry, but your premise is wrong. If you create a functional index on `first_name || ' ' || last_name`, then PostgreSQL is smart enough to use it for queries that depend on that expression. (See http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/indexes-expressional.html, which -- funnily enough -- uses this exact example.) The reason that this query is not amenable to indexing, if you want to raise that point, is the `ilike`.

Comment: You're right. I know enough about Postgresql to know about the function index (a lot of databases have it) but didn't look into the particulars of `ilike`. So create the index on `lower( first_name || ' ' || last_name)` and change the expression to "where people_full_name like lower( 'bat man' )" (or even "where people_full_name = lower( 'bat man' )" since wildcards are not used. Of course, 'bat man' would not be hard coded as in our examples.